# Java interview question: get entry by two fields in O(log(n)) time

Tags: java, algorithm, concurrency, binary-tree

Hi had an interview task, the idea is to store elements with fields: `id`, `name`, `updateTime`;

There should be methods `add(Element)`, `getElement(id)`, `getLastUpdatedElements()`

**Requirements:**

- code should be on Java
- Should be thread safe
- Upper bound of computational complexiy for **all these methods** should be O(log(n))

**Notes**

- Update time of any element can be changed in runtime
- getLastUpdatedElements - returns updated last minute elements

**My thoughts**

I can not use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` because it will take O(N) to find last updated elements if the key is `id`, what breaks the requirement.

To fit O(log(N)) complexity with `getLastUpdatedElements()` I can use `ConcurrentSkipListSet` with comparator by `updateTime` but in that case it will take O(N) to get element by ID. (Please note that in this case `add(Element)` is O(log(N)) since we know updateTime for newly created elements)

I can use two trees, first one with comparator by id, second - with comparator by `updateTime`, but all access methods I should make synchronize what makes my programm single threaded

I think I'm close, just need to find how to get element with O(log(N)) but my thoughts are running out.

Comment: It sounds like you are referring to a programming language specific implementation of some data structure operations.  If so, which language is that?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that java

Comment: I don't understand the `getElement(Element)`. You pass the element and you want it back?

Comment: (Maybe have a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/treeset-in-java-with-examples/ ? )

Comment: @ChatterOne agree, thats a typo. Its required to get element by Id. I fixed the post

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood you correctly.

If you need to store the elements and have an "add" and "get" time as low as (log(N)), that sounds like classic hash map (which uses linked list hash and binary tree if search time reaches a certain threshold - since java 8 I believe).
so in the worst case it's log(N).

for the "get last updated" function: you can store each updated element in a stack (not really a stack, just a list you keep adding into) and when the function is performed. just perform a binary search on the list. when you reach the first item that has been updated in the last minute - just return the index to that item.

that way you only perform binary search (log(N)).

oh and of course just have a lock for those two data structures.
if you really want to dig into it performance-wise, you can implement two locks: one for inserting/updating entries, and one just for reading them.
similar to the "readers-writers problem" like so: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/readers-writers-problem

Comment: I wrote about that solution in "My Thoughts" section. In this case all access to the structures (map and stack) will be in sychronized block what actually makes program - single threaded

Comment: "synchronized" does not mean "single-threaded". you misunderstood what multithreading is

Comment: Whenever you want thread safe code you need to enforce locking in some way (if you have mutual information ofcourse). But if you limit locking (or synchronized blocks if you really want) to its bare minimum - it is thread safe and still allows for cuncurrency